# iOS connect to Magento using OAuth

Tags: ios, magento, oauth

I am trying to connect to Magento REST with OAuth authentication on iOS. I already have: consumer_key, consumer_secret, token, token_secret and the url. With Chrome Rest Client I can connect without problems but in iOS using OAUthiOS library I can not. This library has some example to authenticate to Facebook and Twitter but what I need is to connect to my rest services.

What I have tried so far:

```
NSString *key = @"Authorization";
NSString *value = @"OAuth realm="http://www.myweb.com/",oauth_consumer_key="xxxx",oauth_token="yyyyy",oauth_nonce="zzzz",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1111111",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="wwwwww"";

request = [[OAuthIORequest alloc] init];    
[request addHeaderWithKey:key andValue:value];

[request get:PRODUCTS_SERVICE success:^(NSDictionary *output, NSString *body, NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse)
 {
     NSLog(@"body %@", body);
 }];
```

But nothing happend. What should I do? Is there any framework better?

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing happened?  Can you log the other params to the block?

Comment: No, I cann't. The code inside the block is never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this issue using another framework: AFNetworking and AFOAuth1Client instead of OAUthiOS.

```
AFOAuth1Client * client = [[AFOAuth1Client alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BASE_URL] key:CONSUMER_KEY secret:CONSUMER_SECRET];
[client setOauthAccessMethod:@"GET"];
[client setSignatureMethod:AFHMACSHA1SignatureMethod];
[client setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
[client setAccessToken:[[AFOAuth1Token alloc] initWithKey:TOKEN secret:TOKEN_SECRET session:nil expiration:nil renewable:FALSE]];

NSMutableURLRequest * request =[client requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:PRODUCTS_SERVICE parameters:nil];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[client registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"Response: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
[operation start];
```

Comment: i got problem with sign in Magento too, can you provide more detail source code!